# Expressions Blend Font size differences from property panel and XAML output

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

Does anyone what the difference is or why in Expressions Blend, when I tell the font to be a size in the property panel, in the XAML it outputs as something completely difference.

Example: in the property panel it tell the text to be 140pt.  But when I look in the XAML, the FontSize property comes out to 186.667.

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XAML font sizes don't go by the normal 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16pt and so on, but from 1 onward so 186.667 is the equivalent to 140pt font.

Comment: Oh, it is one of those things. Like the old HTML <Font> tag sizes.

Comment: It's a Double in XAML, so you're looking at px VS pt and interpreted.

Comment: yup if it really bothers you you can explicitly set it as fontsize="140pt" If you have OCD that will probably help :)

Comment: @CJK.  Yeh, coming from a web development background and specifying pixels or pts specifically, OCD can tend to creep in.  Thanks